# How to use GoogleCharts in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've tried with plenty of resources online that say how to use GoogleCharts in Angular. They all say how to include them in a `.js` file, like in this one.

http://plnkr.co/edit/7UUfcq4dD7nd4MylB4ni?p=info

But I am working on the project that has a structure like separate files for HTML, CSS and TypeScript. I need to include the `js` inside the TypeScript so that I can dynamically load the data from the TypeScript to the `js` file where the details for the charts reside.

There are libraries in angular components for GoogleCharts like this one https://angular-google-chart.github.io/angular-google-chart/, but I need to use it as a `js` file to customize it better.

Comment: is this angular or angularjs related?

Comment: It is Angular. Tag's corrected.